# Python SQLite DB query returning nothing for each row

Tags: python, sqlite, testcomplete

I'm using python in TestComplete to conduct a db query, but the results seem to be empty strings and do not match the data in the table I queried. The file is a s3db file. Does that matter?

Using:

TestComplete Version 14

imported sqlite3 into python file

I've:

-Tried running the same query in SQLite. It returned the expected result

-Verified the connection is established with the correct db

```
---python
import sqlite3

def getInfo():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(db)
    c = conn.cursor()

    try:
        c.execute('SELECT Column_Name FROM Table_Name')
        results = c.fetchall()
    except:
        Log.Error("Query execution failed") 

    for x in results:
        Log.Message(x) `enter code here`
        #Log.Message() works like a print statement in testcomplete.
---
```

Actual Output:
The program runs without errors, but the results come back as 15 lines of blank rows. 15 is the number of records within the table, so I know it's looking in the right place, but it seems like it's not identifying that there's information stored here.

Expected Output:
15 lines of data contained within the Column I specified in the query.

Answer (score -1):

There is no error with sqlite3 and your DB operations. The issue is with *Log.Message* and what it expects as an argument. Within TestComplete, *Log.Message* requires variable arguments of type *Variant*, which can be any of the supported data types within TestComplete; *String*, *Double/Real*, *Boolean*, *Date/Time*, *Object* (i.e. TestComplete-recognised UI objects) and *Integer*. 
*Log.Message* cannot accept arguments of the type returned by *cursor.fetchall*'s rows.

So you'd need to convert each row into a String, e.g.

```
for x in results:
    msg = ('{0} : {1}'.format(x[0], x[1]))
    Log.Message(msg)
```

Comment: If the imported sqlite3 library wasn't working, wouldn't it have thrown an error?

Comment: @bonzi You are correct, it would - e.g. if you try to "import sqlite" TC errors out in an expected fashion. As such, my original answer - pertaining to placing external packages in <TestComplete>\Bin\Extensions\Python\Python36\Lib - is not applicable.   
 The issue is more to do with the type of the result row, and what Log.message expects. See my revised answer.